# Multiple Segues to one ViewController with NavigationController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

i have one question about using multiple segues to one ViewController. Ill try to create an article management, so you can add/edit/delete articles.

When you add a new article you can choose between a maincategory and a subcategory, choose the article and then edit some inital values.

[image]

but if ill try to edit one of my selected articles, i would like to jump to the "latest" ViewController in navigation stack.

I thought i could easily create another segue to my last viewController, but ill always get an error when i try to load this segue (i guess this could be a problem with the existing NavigationController).

I could provide some code, but i dont know if this is a possible solution to solve such things - or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to perform the segue?

Comment: Unexpected Breakpoint - i guess the problem here is only the missing NC. Solved it by adding another NC to the last view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but the new segue should take you to a navigation controller that just contains the last view controller (as the root). In this way you are duplicating the normal situation but with only 1 view controller.

If you wanted to allow the last view controller to have a 'back' button which took you to some 'earlier' screens (if that makes any kind of sense in your app) then you would need to write some code. It's more likely that other screens should be accessed via bar button items or similar (which would also likely be done in code).

Comment: Thank you for your anser. I dont need a back button here - so solution 1 would be great. Can i do this in Storyboard Editor? So you mean embed the last ViewController into a new NavigationController, connect my MainTableView to this NavigationController and connect already existing Segue to the ViewController directly, without using this "new" NavigationController?

Comment: Perfect. Tried this and it works like a charm. Thank you so much!